# Developing custom effects for raspivid?

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspivid

Has anyone created a custom effect for `raspivid`'s `-ifx` option? From a quick look at the [Github repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/d819af5de65a06cc6ba5867cf594149f8d0eb566/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam), it seems there is it might be run through the [MMAL interface](https://github.com/techyian/MMALSharp/wiki/What-is-MMAL%3F) but I have no idea where to get started there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom effects are part of the closed-source GPU firmware which only Raspberry Pi and Broadcom engineers can change. You can add further effects in post-processing (on the CPU) though.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, @flakeshake is right that it's a closed source system, but it does seem possible to run your own GL shaders within the `raspistill` system by modifying and building your own version [from the source files](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/gl_scenes/mirror.c). It does also seem possible to use GL shaders elsewhere for faster image processing, such as [this example](http://robotblogging.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/gpu-accelerated-camera-processing-on.html) which may be helpful to others.